# Is there a way to flush the entire CPU cache related to a program?

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, optimization, cpu-cache

On `x86-64` platforms, the `CLFLUSH` assembly instruction allows to flush the cache line corresponding to a given address. Instead of flushing the cache related to a specific address, would there be a way to flush the entire cache (either the cache related to the program being executed, or the entire cache), for example by making it full of dummy contents (or any other approach I would not be aware of):

- using only standard C++17?
- using standard C++17 and compiler intrinsics if necessary?

What would be the contents of the following function: (the function should work regardless of compiler optimizations)?

```
void flush_cache() 
{
    // Contents
}
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the use case of this?

Comment: Leaving aside the C++ aspect of this, I don't believe there is any instruction to completely wipe the cache. The closest thing you can get to it is to pull huge amounts of data through it to completely evict everything that's already in it. Then you would need to do it on each core since the lower level caches are private.

Comment: @Mysticial: then the whole question is how to implement this? For an example of use case: micro-benchmarking.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think this is possible to do purely with C++ even with intrinsics. You need the ability to set thread affinities and I don't believe C++ has that concept. You also either need a way to obtain the cache sizes or make assumptions about the cache. So I'm not sure portability here is easy to achieve.

Comment: According to the x86-64 software developers manual the instructions for invalidate the entire cache are privileged so I doubt that any sane operating system will allow them to be called from user code.

Comment: Just loop through all your memory and flush every 64th (usual cache line size) address. Finally you flush the line, where your loop resides in, but after this instruction, this cache line would be loaded again. You probably cannot flush memory of the kernel, that holds data of your programm. Anyway, why do you want this?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it and *motivate it*. We cannot read your mind, and there is no reason -and it has no sense- to do this in *standard C++* (which does not *know* or *care* about caches).

Comment: I don't think the question is clear.  As I understand it, the CLFLUSH instruction ensures that cached data is written back to memory, but the question sounds like the goal is to clear the data that's in the cache.  Those are different operations.  What's the actual goal?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: `clflush` *does* also ensure the line is evicted, so next time you read the line it's fetched from memory.  The much more recently-introduces `clwb` does *just* write-back without eviction.  The use-case is for [non-volatile memory attached directly to the CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVDIMM), where you want to commit to persistent storage without making the next read slow.  See https://danluu.com/clwb-pcommit/, but note that `pcommit` never made it into silicon, and is now deprecated or non-existent, and `clwb` or `clflushopt` + `sfence` are sufficient.

Comment: see [Benchmarking affected by VCL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21517601/2521214) and  [Cache size estimation on your system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21509808/2521214) they both are related to each other and might help you with your problem (without the need for ring priviledges or asm).

Comment: @PeterCordes You where absolutely right with the edit of my code in the other Q/A. Has not been using x86 asm for a while (`jp` is on Z80 :))

Comment: @Spektre: You're welcome :).  BTW, you can @-notify people who have edited a post, so you could have commented there.

Comment: @PeterCordes thx didn't know that I taught notification works only for those who are present in comment thread and author of thread.

Comment: I've been running into this while attempting to design and profile data structures that optimize for the cache miss case. Forcing the *instructions* to cache miss is quite tricky.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For links to related questions about clearing caches (especially on x86), see the first answer on [WBINVD instruction usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745665/wbinvd-instruction-usage/6745706#6745706).

---

**No, you cannot do this reliably or efficiently with pure ISO C++**.  It doesn't know or care about CPU caches.  The best you could do is touch a lot of memory so everything else ends up getting evicted<sup>1</sup>, but this is not what you're really asking for.  (Of course, flushing *all* cache is by definition inefficient...)
See *[Flushing the cache to prevent benchmarking fluctiations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460744/flushing-the-cache-to-prevent-benchmarking-fluctiations/49077734#49077734)* for some tips about implementation details if you go that route.

CPU cache management functions / intrinsics / asm instructions are implementation-specific extensions to the C++ language.  But other than inline asm, no C or C++ implementations that I'm aware of provide a way to flush *all* cache, rather than a range of addresses.  That's because it's *not* a normal thing to do.

---

**On x86, for example, the asm instruction you're looking for is `wbinvd`.**  It writes-back any dirty lines before evicting, unlike `invd` (which drops cache *without* write-back, [useful when leaving cache-as-RAM mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775371/what-use-is-the-invd-instruction)).  So in theory `wbinvd` has no architectural effect, only microarchitectural, but it's so slow that's it's a privileged instruction.  As [Intel's insn ref manual entry for `wbinvd`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/WBINVD) points out, it will increase interrupt latency, because it is not itself interruptible and may have to wait for 8 MiB or more of dirty L3 cache to be flushed.  i.e. delaying interrupts for that long can be considered an architectural effect, unlike most timing effects.  It's also complicated on a multi-core system because it has to flush caches for *all* cores.

I don't think there's any way to use it in user-space (ring 3) on x86.  Unlike `cli` / `sti` and `in`/`out`, it's not enabled by the IO-privilege level (which you can set on Linux with an [`iopl()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html)).  So `wbinvd` only works when actually running in ring 0 (i.e. in kernel code).  See [Privileged Instructions and CPU Ring Levels](https://bsodtutorials.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/privileged-instructions-and-cpu-ring-levels/).

But if you're writing a kernel (or freestanding program that runs in ring0) in GNU C or C++, you could use `asm("wbinvd" ::: "memory");`.  On a computer running actual DOS, normal programs run in real mode (which doesn't have any lower-privilege levels; everything is effectively kernel).  That would be another way to run a microbenchmark that needs to run privileged instructions to avoid kernel<->userspace transition overhead for `wbinvd`, and also has the convenience of running under an OS so you can use a filesystem.  Putting your microbenchmark into a Linux kernel module might be easier than booting FreeDOS from a USB stick or something, though.  Especially if you want control of turbo frequency stuff.

---

The only reason I can think of that you might want this is for some kind of experiment to figure out how the internals of a specific CPU are designed.  So the details of exactly how it's done are critical.  It doesn't make sense to me to even want a portable / generic way to do this.

Or maybe in a kernel before reconfiguring physical memory layout, e.g. so there's now an MMIO region for an ethernet card where there used to be normal DRAM.  But in that case your code is already totally arch-specific.

---

**Normally when you want / need to flush caches for correctness reasons, you *know* which address range needs flushing**.  e.g. when writing drivers on architectures with DMA that isn't cache coherent, so write-back happens before a DMA read, and doesn't step on a DMA write.  (And the eviction part is important for DMA reads, too: you don't want the old cached value).  But x86 has cache-coherent DMA these days, because modern designs build the memory controller into the CPU die so system traffic can snoop L3 on the way from PCIe to memory.

The major case outside of drivers where you need to worry about caches is with JIT code-generation on non-x86 architectures with non-coherent instruction caches.  If you (or a JIT library) write some machine code into a `char[]` buffer and cast it to a function pointer, architectures like ARM don't guarantee that code-fetch will "see" that newly-written data.

This is why gcc provides [`__builtin__clear_cache`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).  It doesn't necessarily flush anything, only makes sure it's safe to execute that memory as code.  x86 has instruction caches that are coherent with data caches and supports [self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395557/observing-stale-instruction-fetching-on-x86-with-self-modifying-code) without any special syncing instructions.  See [godbolt for x86 and AArch64](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27//+make+it+safe+to+cast+p+to+a+function+pointer+and+call+it%0A//+after+writing+instructions+into+a+buffer.%0A%0Avoid+flushcache(char+*p)+%7B%0A++++__builtin___clear_cache(p,+p%2B128)%3B++//+128+bytes%0A%7D%0A//+zero+instructions+on+x86,+because+I-cache+is+already+coherent.%0A%0A//+But+since+it+takes+a+start/end+address+range,+it+would+use+clflush+if+it+did+do+anything,%0A//+not+the+privileged+WBINVD+which+flushes+*all*+cache%0A%0A%0A//+It!%27s+NOT+a+no-op:++Without+it+or+other+barrier,+stores+are+optimized+away+as+%22dead%22.%0A%0A%0A//+https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/the-repetitive-byte-counter/160236%23160236%0A%0A/****+Test+harness:+JIT+x86+code+into+a+buffer+and+call+it+****/%0A//+compile+with+gcc+-O3+-no-pie+-fno-pie+-m32+-z+execstack%0A//+or+use+mprotect+or+VirtualProtect+instead+of+-z+execstack%0A//+or+mmap(PROT_EXEC%7CPROT_READ%7CPROT_WRITE)+instead+of+malloc%0A%0A%0A//+declare+a+function+pointer+to+a+regparm%3D1+function%0Atypedef+int+__attribute__((regparm(1)))+(*eax_arg_funcptr_t)(unsigned+arg)%3B%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char+*argv%5B%5D)%0A%7B%0A++++if+(argc%3C3)+return+-1%3B%0A++++unsigned+N%3Dstrtoul(argv%5B1%5D,+NULL,+0),+M+%3D+strtoul(argv%5B2%5D,+NULL,+0)%3B%0A%0A++++char+*execbuf+%3D+malloc(M%2B1)%3B++//+heap+is+often+executable+when+stack+isn!%27t%0A++++memset(execbuf,+0x48,+M)%3B++//+times+M++dec+eax%0A++++execbuf%5BM%5D+%3D+0xC3%3B+++++++++//+ret%0A%0A++++//+Tell+GCC+we!%27re+about+to+run+this+data+as+code.++x86+has+coherent+I-cache,%0A++++//+but+this+also+stops+optimization+from+removing+these+as+dead+stores.%0A++++__builtin___clear_cache+(execbuf,+execbuf%2BM%2B1)%3B%0A++++//+comment+it+out+and+the+memset+disappears%0A++++%0A+++++//+++asm(%22%22+:::+%22memory%22)%3B++//+compiler+memory+barrier+works+too.%0A%0A++++eax_arg_funcptr_t+execfunc+%3D+(eax_arg_funcptr_t)+execbuf%3B%0A++++int+res+%3D+execfunc(N)%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25u+%3D%3D+%25u++%3D%3E++%25d%5Cn%22,+N,M,+res+)%3B%0A++++return+!!!!res%3B+++//+exit+status+only+takes+the+low+8+bits+of+return+value%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.18056725638866,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-m32+-xc+-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:29.486099410278023,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g630,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-O3+-Wall%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM64+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), and note that `__builtin__clear_cache` compiles to zero instructions for x86, but has an effect on surrounding code: without it, gcc can optimize away stores to a buffer before casting to a function pointer and calling.  (It doesn't realize that data is being used as code, so it thinks they're dead stores and eliminates them.)

Despite the name,  `__builtin__clear_cache` is totally unrelated to `wbinvd`.  It needs an address-range as args so it's not going to flush and invalidate the entire cache.   It also doesn't use use `clflush`, `clflushopt`, or `clwb` to actually write-back (and optionally evict) data from cache.

When you need to flush some cache for correctness, you only want to flush a range of addresses, *not* slow the system down by flushing all the caches.

---

**It rarely if ever makes sense to intentionally flush caches for performance reasons, at least on x86**.  Sometimes you can use pollution-minimizing prefetch to read data without as much cache pollution, or use NT stores to write around cache.  But doing "normal" stuff and then `clflushopt` after touching some memory for the last time is generally not worth it in normal cases.  Like a store, it has to go all the way through the memory hierarchy to make sure it finds and flushes any copy of that line anywhere.

There isn't a light-weight instruction designed as a performance hint, like the opposite of `_mm_prefetch`.

---

The only cache-flushing you can do in user-space on x86 is with `clflush` / `clflushopt`.  (Or with NT stores, which also evict the cache line if it was hot before hand).   Or of course creating conflict evictions for known L1d size and associativity, like writing to multiple lines at multiples of 4kiB which all map to the same set in a 32k / 8-way L1d.

There's an Intel intrinsic [`_mm_clflush(void const *p)`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&text=clflush&ig_expand=770) wrapper for [`clflush`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CLFLUSH) (and another for [`clflushopt`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CLFLUSHOPT)), but these can only flush cache lines by (virtual) address.  You could loop over all the cache lines in all the pages your process has mapped...  (But that can only flush your own memory, not cache lines that are caching kernel data, like the kernel stack for your process or its `task_struct`, so the first system-call will still be faster than if you had flushed everything).

There's a Linux system call wrapper to portably evict a range of addresses: [`cacheflush(char *addr, int nbytes, int flags)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/cacheflush.2.html).  Presumably the implementation on x86 uses `clflush` or `clflushopt` in a loop, if it's supported on x86 at all.  The man page says it first appeared in MIPS Linux "but
nowadays, Linux provides a cacheflush() system call on some other
architectures, but with different arguments."

**I don't think there's a Linux system call that exposes `wbinvd`,** but you could write a kernel module that adds one.

---

**Recent x86 extensions introduced more cache-control instructions, but still only by address to control specific cache lines**.  The use-case is for [non-volatile memory attached directly to the CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVDIMM), such as [Intel Optane DC Persistent Memory](https://superuser.com/questions/1389552/can-intel-optane-memory-compensate-for-less-ram/1391391#1391391).  If you want to commit to persistent storage without making the next read slow, you can use [`clwb`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CLWB).  But note that `clwb` is not *guaranteed* to avoid eviction, it's merely *allowed* to.  It might run the same as `clflushopt`, like [may be the case on SKX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573776/exclusive-access-to-l1-cacheline-on-x86/51574318?noredirect=1#comment96553954_51574318).

See https://danluu.com/clwb-pcommit/, but note that `pcommit` isn't required: Intel decided to simplify the ISA before releasing any chips that need it, so `clwb` or `clflushopt` + `sfence` are sufficient.  See https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/09/12/deprecate-pcommit-instruction.

Anyway, this is the kind of cache-control that's relevant for modern CPUs.  Whatever experiment you're doing requires ring0 and assembly on x86.

---

**Footnote 1: Touching a lot of memory: pure ISO C++17**

You *could* maybe allocate a very large buffer and then `memset` it (so those writes will pollute all the (data) caches with that data), then unmap it.  If `delete` or `free` actually returns the memory to the OS right away, then it will no longer be part of your process's address space, so only a few cache lines of other data will still be hot: probably a line or two of stack (assuming you're on a C++ implementation that uses a stack, as well as running programs under an OS...).  And of course this only pollutes data caches, not instruction caches, and as Basile points out, some levels of cache are private per-core, and OSes can migrate processes between CPUs.

Also, beware that using an actual `memset` or `std::fill` function call, or a loop that optimizes to that, could be optimized to use cache-bypassing or pollution-reducing stores.  And I also implicitly assumed that your code is running on a CPU with write-allocate caches, instead of write-through on store misses (because all modern CPUs are designed this way).  x86 supports WT memory regions on a per-page basis, but mainstream OSes use WB pages for all "normal" memory.

Doing something that can't optimize away and touches a lot of memory (e.g. a prime sieve with a `long` array instead of a bitmap) would be more reliable, but of course still dependent on cache pollution to evict other data.  Just reading large amounts of data isn't reliable either; some CPUs  implement adaptive replacement policies that reduce pollution from sequential accesses, so looping over a big array hopefully doesn't evict lots of useful data.  E.g. [the L3 cache in Intel IvyBridge and later](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/) does this.

Comment: Can you describe how the stated cache eviction would be performed? For example, if I want to evict the cache line where a given (virtual) memory address A is mapped to, I would just access random addresses at A+i*64KiB where i=1,..,N?

Comment: @Patrick: Yes.  For L2 cache, use a hugepage (which guarantees contiguous physical memory) so virtual stride = physical stride.  For L1d cache, the necessary stride to alias the same set is typically 4kiB, so the same offset in *any* page is fine.  Cache replacement is typically pseudo-LRU not true-LRU, so touching 8 other lines isn't *guaranteed* to evict the oldest line, but probabilistically it's probably fine.  (If this strategy is worth even considering for any given application where the producer can waste a huge amount of extra time to help the next reader a bit).

Comment: @Patrick: It doesn't have to be random addresses, sequential is fine.  It's actually good if HW prefetch notices the strided read access pattern, although that won't really matter if you do them all at once.  The next address calculation doesn't depend on the previous load so memory-level parallelism in the CPU core can have 8 to 12 demand loads outstanding.  (I assume loads are as good as stores for forcing eviction, unless there's some bias in the cache towards evicting clean lines over dirty lines.)  If you have multiple such producers, they can all share a read set that can stay hot in L3.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I am trying to evict a certain address from the cache that refers to an element X of an array. So if I want to evict it from L1D I would just compute the offset of this element X with respect to the page and then use this to access many other pages with same offset until the set is full and the oldest entry is evicted, right?

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, but usually the set is always full with *some* data.  Also eviction is normally [pseudo-LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Pseudo-LRU_(PLRU)) not true-LRU.  ([algorithm LRU, how many bits needed for implement this algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193490))

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**, there is no standard C++ way to do this (even with some compiler intrinsics). [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has [`__builtin__clear_cache` and `__builtin_prefetch`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) probably has them also.

As Johan commented, x86-64 has a privileged instruction for doing what you want, but `__builtin__clear_cache` doesn't use it (and is a no-op on x86-64, because instruction caches are coherent with data caches on that architecture so hardware takes care of syncing recently-stored data before executing it as code).

On Linux, you might (perhaps) use the [cacheflush(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/cacheflush.2.html) Linux specific system call. I never used it, and I don't know if it is implemented on x86-64.

---

BTW, you should not reason on programs, but on [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). Each has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Your question lacks some motivation. If you care about micro-benchmarking, be aware that the kernel scheduler is allowed to reschedule and move your thread or process to some other core at arbitrary machine code instruction (be however aware of [processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)).

> (the function should work regardless of compiler optimizations)?

No, [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) are reordering and rescheduling machine code instructions and often mix several computations related to *different* C++ statements. They are allowed to do some computations at compile-time. Read more about the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule). See CppCon 2017 talk: Matt Godbolt [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4).

Comment: `__builtin__clear_cache` and `cacheflush(2)`  both take a range of virtual addresses, so they don't help at all vs. `_mm_clflush(void*)`.  Also,  `__builtin__clear_cache` is a no-op on x86, because its semantic meaning is to make a buffer of JITed machine-code safe to execute.  I edited to make the answer not actually wrong, but you should probably just remove the first section and leave the good 2nd section.  (My answer covers the details that your first section tried to answer.)

Comment: It's also Possible to use this kernel module on linux https://github.com/batmac/wbinvd